# How to solve non linear equation in R?

Tags: r, statistics, nonlinear-equation

I want to solve a non linear function in R using a loop for 71 years of data.

The equation looks like this:

```
y(i) == -1/k*log(1-k(xi - beta/alpha))
```

where `xi` is the value present in the dataset.

For the first data the equation looks like this:

```
y(1) ==  -1/k*log(1-k(95 - beta/alpha))
```

where 95 is the first value of the list.

The value of `K`, `alpha` and `beta` are already known.

Thank you!

I wrote a loop which will take the values from the list

```
for (i in list) {
  y(i) <- -1/k* log(1-k(xi - beta/alpha))
  print(y1)
}
```

Unfortunately its not working.

Comment: 1)In the loop do you want `xi` or `x[i]`? It seems like you want the latter. 2) `y(i)` should be `y[i]`. 3) There is a `*` missing in `k(95 - beta/alpha)` right after `k`.

Comment: Assuming the values shown `y <- 1:10; alpha <- beta <- k <- 1; beta/alpha - (exp(-(y * k)) - 1)/k`